# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar el funcionamiento de claves foráneas usando el complemento sqlite de ionic para un proyecto de Android?

Tags: ionic, sqlite

Ante todo gracias por tus respuestas. Estoy creando una aplicación de Android Ionic y necesito crear una base de datos con el complemento sqlite. Estas son las tablas que estoy creando:

```
    async database(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.db) this.db = await this.sqlite.create({ name: 'data.db', location: 'default' });
  }

  async createTables(): Promise<void> {
    await this.database();
    await this.db.executeSql(`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS record (
        id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        title       TEXT NOT NULL,
        description TEXT
      );
      `, []).then(data => { console.log(data); });
    await this.db.executeSql(
      `
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recordPage (
        id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
        title             TEXT NOT NULL,
        orderElement    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id  AUTOINCREMENT),
        FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES record(id)
      );
      `, []).then(data => { console.log(data); });

    await this.db.executeSql(//Antes estaba puesto 'order y ahora está puesto 'orderElement' para no tener conflicto
      `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recordRow(
          id                INTEGER NOT NULL,
          orderElement      INTEGER NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY(id AUTOINCREMENT),
          FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES recordPage(id)
        );
        `, []).then(data => { console.log(data); });
```

Cuando exporto la base de datos que creé al ejecutar la aplicación, veo que tengo todas las claves primarias y foráneas correctamente insertadas. Si borro datos de una tabla que tiene una clave foránea, los datos de las otras tablas a las que hacen referencia estas claves foráneas no se borran. En otras palabras, las claves foráneas no funcionan.

si introduzco datos, a modo de ejemplo en la tabla recordPage, me debería ded saltar un error si el id de esta tabla no coincide con el id de la tabla record. Pero me introduce los datos sin saltarme una alarta. Pero si exporto esta tabla a un lector de sqlite externo, no me deja insertar datos en recordPage, me salta el error de que tiene una clave foránea.

**¿Saben cómo puedo activar claves foráneas con el complemento Ionic sqlite?**

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Al final he podido activar la funcionalidad de las claves foráneas ejecutando el siguiente método después de ejecutar el método database(). El método que habilita estas claves foráneas, por si le sirve a alguien, es el siguiente:

```
  enableForeignKeys(): Promise<any> {
    return this.db.executeSql('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON', [])
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("PRAGMA maybe ok");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log("erreur pragma");
      });
  }
```